# ubuntu 11.10 /var/log/auth.log

Tags: ssh, configuration, authentication, logging

I use Ubuntu 11.10. And I want it to write logging messages about failed ssh log in attempts to `/var/log/auth.log`. In my understanding `/var/log/auth.log` is supposed to hold all failed ssh connection attempts.

How am I supposed to do? (What do I need to check? How can I configure my machine?)

```
:~$ sudo ls -al /var/log/auth.log
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm 0 2011-09-11 06:25 /var/log/auth.log
:~$ sudo ls -al /var/log/wtmp
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root utmp 15744 2013-03-21 18:09 /var/log/wtmp
```

Currently `/var/log/wtmp` is handled very well as you could find it above. But /var/log/auth.log is EMPTY. I'd like my machine handle `/var/log/auth.log` as it is supposed to be.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I checked `/etc/rsyslog.conf`
And I found someone switched it with an unknown `.conf` file.
But the original `.conf` file was saved with a different name - `/etc/rsyslog.conf.original`

This had been done before I start using of my virtual server service. Yes I use virtual server service.

The service operator or administrator did this into the images they provide.
And I don't know why they do this. And I wonder why they do this.

Just with recovering to the original `.conf` file my problem is solved.

Thank you for your concern.